# shehecheyanu on eruv tavshilin

Tags: mitzvah, shehecheyanu, eruv-tavshilin

It is a rabbinical *mitzvah* to make *eruv tavshilin*, it even comes with a blessing. If so, why don't we make a *shehecheyanu* on it?

Comment: Because it is a necessity,not like a mitzvah of time.

Comment: Lots of rabbinical mitzvot come with blessings but don't include *shehechiyanu*.  Could you explain why you think this one would be different?  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio. He considers that it should, because his point of departure is Chanukiah and Megillah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some suggestions at this Web site: http://dinonline.org/2017/05/02/why-dont-we-say-a-shehechiyanu-on-the-mitzvah-of-eruv-tavshilin/

Comment: Please [edit] in a summary per site policy https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2187/759, otherwise this might be converted to a comment.